# Pattern matching in Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

For example, my input for variable day can be Monday or Monday, Tuesday or Monday,..,Friday and I'm trying to use regex in python to just provide a pattern and check its input.

```
result = re.compile(r'\([S|M|T|W|Th|F|Sa]\)|\([S|M|T|W|Th|F|Sa],[S|M|T|W|Th|F|Sa]+\)')
day = "(T,Th)"
if result.match(day):
  print "matched"
else:
  print 'not'
```

What if the given input is (T,Th,F) or (T,Th,F,Sa)? What should I do to my pattern to handle these kind of input? Is there any solution so it wont be lengthy?

Comment: `[]` represents a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), `|` is not an `or` operation there. Use `(S|M|T|W|Th|F|Sa)`...

Answer (score 4):

An answer without regex would be:

```
week = ["S", "M", "T", "W", "Th", "F", "Sa"]
days = "(T,Th,C)"
no_match = False
for day in days[1:-1].split(","): #split separates your days-string, [1:-1] removes brackets
    if day not in week:
        no_match = True
        break
if no_match:
    print "not"
else:
    print "matched"
```

the [1:-1] are slicing notation, bascially it creates a string starting at character with index 1 (= 2nd character) and ending at the next-to-last character. In fact it removes the brackets.

Comment: @user3226156 Basically excluding the first and last character. In his example, only includes `T,Th,C`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this regex:

```
\((S|M|T|W|Th|F|Sa)(,\s*(S|M|T|W|Th|F|Sa))*\)
```

The `(S|M|T|W|Th|F|Sa)` matches any weekday. Be careful to use **round parentheses**, not square brackets, as these represent character classes (see Ashwini Chaudhary's comment)

This will match, for example:

- `(M, T, W)`
- `(M)`
- `(T, Sa, Fr)`
- `(T,M,Th)`

Comment: I see, that's what '*' is used for.

Comment: @user3226156 Yes, exactly. It means 'zero or more of this'.